# ** EDIT: Update a value (which is a list) in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary D as follows

```
D = {'first':['a','b','b'], 'second':['alpha','beta','kappa']}
```

sorry for my lack of clarification. My new dict would look like this:

```
D = {'first': True, 'second':['alpha','beta','kappa']}
```

I would like to search each pairing in D and if a key has repeated values in the list (like for D['first']) I want to replace that value with True.

How can I go about this using loops and for statements? (Its part of a problem from my assignment and these are the restrictions)

Comment: Why do you want to use loops or for statements? Also, what exactly is the expected output?

Comment: @ReutSharabani: He wants to have this: `D={'first':['a', 'b', True], 'second':['alpha', 'beta', 'kappa']}`

Comment: It reads as if he wants `'first':['a',True, True], 'second':['alpha','beta','kappa']` - so I'd rather he writes it.

Answer (score 0):

hi dude if I understand you correctly it could be:

```
dic = {'mykey':'123345678', 'otherkey':44}
'mykey' in dic
>>>True
```

or with generators for your example:

```
dic['mykey'] = list(map(lambda x: bool(x), dic['otherkey']))
print dic
>>>{'mykey': [True, True, True], 'otherkey': [9, 4, 7]}
```

or for filter:

```
dic['mykey'] = list(map(lambda x: bool(x) if (x==9 or x==4 or x==3) else False, dic['otherkey']))
print dic
{'mykey': [True, True, False], 'otherkey': [9, 4, 7]}
```

But i don't understand for what do you need a loop? what do want obtain in the output?

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to do it only with `for` statements, but here you have it combining with `while`:

```
for key in dict.keys():
    indexCounter = 0
    while indexCounter < len(dict[key]):
        otherIndexCounter = 0
        while otherIndexCounter < len(dict[key]):
            if indexCounter != otherIndexCounter:
                if dict[key][indexCounter] == dict[key][otherIndexCounter]:
                    dict[key][otherIndexCounter] = True
            otherIndexCounter += 1
        indexCounter += 1
```

Example:

```
def changeRepeated(dict):
    for key in dict.keys():
        indexCounter = 0
        while indexCounter < len(dict[key]):
            otherIndexCounter = 0
            while otherIndexCounter < len(dict[key]):
                if indexCounter != otherIndexCounter:
                    if dict[key][indexCounter] == dict[key][otherIndexCounter]:
                        dict[key][otherIndexCounter] = True
                otherIndexCounter += 1
            indexCounter += 1    
    return dict

dictionary = {'first':['a','b','b'], 'second':['alpha','beta','kappa']}
dictionary = changeRepeated(dictionary)

print(dictionary)
>>> {'first': ['a', 'b', True], 'second': ['alpha', 'beta', 'kappa']}
```

So that's your **output**:

```
{'first': ['a', 'b', True], 'second': ['alpha', 'beta', 'kappa']}
```

I hope it helped :)